# How can I replace svm.SVR 'rbf' kernel in sklearn using my own RBF function?

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, svm

I have developed the code below for starting a project for svm method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

housing = load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[housing['data'], housing['target']],
              columns= np.append(housing['feature_names'], ['target']))

features = df.columns.tolist()
label = features[-1]
features = features[:-1]

x_train = df[features].iloc[:400]
y_train = df[label].iloc[:400]

x_test = df[features].iloc[400:]
y_test = df[label].iloc[400:]

svr = svm.SVR(kernel='rbf')
svr.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = svr.predict(x_test)

print(mean_absolute_error(y_pred, y_test))
```

Now I want to use my customized rbf kernel which is:

```
def my_rbf(feat, lbl):
#feat = feat.values
    #lbl = lbl.values
    ans = np.array([])
    gamma = 0.000005
    for i in range(len(feat)):
        ans = np.append(ans, np.exp(-gamma * np.dot(feat[i]-lbl[i], feat[i]-lbl[i])))

    return ans
```

Then I changed `svm.SVR(kernel=my_rbf)` But I get plenty of errors while modifying it in any way. I also tried to use a simple function like `np.dot(feat-lbl,feat-lbl)` which worked fine in `SVR.fit` method but in `svr.predict` some error occurred which said that shape of input matrix has to be like [n_samples_test, n_samples_train].

I'm stymied to deal with the errors. Can anyone help me make this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15798/how-to-calculate-a-gaussian-kernel-effectively-in-numpy), RBF function which I was looking for (takes training featues as X and testing features as X' as inputs) and outputs [n_training_samples, n_testing_samples] as explained more thoroughly in [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#using-python-functions-as-kernels), is something like this:

```
def my_kernel(X,Y):
    K = np.zeros((X.shape[0],Y.shape[0]))
    for i,x in enumerate(X):
        for j,y in enumerate(Y):
            K[i,j] = np.exp(-1*np.linalg.norm(x-y)**2)
    return K

clf=SVR(kernel=my_kernel)
```

which results exactly equal to:

```
clf=SVR(kernel="rbf",gamma=1)
```

In terms of speed it lacks performance as efecient as the default svm library rbf. It could be useful to use [static typing](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/cythonize.html) of cython library for indexes and also using [memory-views](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) for numpy arrays to speed it up a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

The custom kernel method `my_rbf` you coded uses both X (features) and y (labels). You cannot evaluate this function during predictions as you have no access to labels. The  custom kernel if flawed.

**Backgroud**

The RBF function is defined as below (from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel))

[image]

where `x` and `x'` are two feature (X) vectors.

Let `H(X)` is a function with transforms a vector `X` to other dimension (normally to very very high dimension). SVM needs to calculate the dot product between all combinations of the feature vectors (ie all `H(X)`'s). So if `H(X1) . H(X2) = K(X1, X2)` then `K` is called the kernel function or kernalization of `H`. So instead of transforming the points `X1` and `X2` to very high dimensions and calculating the dot product there, `K` calculates it directly from `X1` and `X2`.

**Conclusion**
The `my_rbf` is not a valid kernel function simply because it uses labels (`Y`s). It should be only on the feature vectors.

Comment: OK then, How should I replace the `my_rbf` function and make the code work like when using default kernel = 'rbf' ?